# Exception when linking a fxml file with java

Tags: java, fxml

I'm trying to learn FXML, so I followed this guide https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm and basically, I've copied and pasted the code contained there.

Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("test.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);

        stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

test.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

    <Text text="Welcome" 
        GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"
        GridPane.columnSpan="2"/>

    <Label text="User Name:"
        GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

    <TextField 
        GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

    <Label text="Password:"
        GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>

    <PasswordField fx:id="passwordField" 
        GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
```

This code gives me the following errors

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$412(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/michelangelo/code/javaFX/part1/test.fxml

        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2543)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
        at Main.start(Main.java:10)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$419(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$399(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$397(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$398(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$203(GtkApplication.java:139)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[13,6]
Message: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:604)
        at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(StreamReaderDelegate.java:88)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2513)
        ... 17 more
Exception running application Main
```

I tried my best to fix the problem but i can't figure it out how to do that.

Comment: You're missing a root element in your xml, that is an element that contains all the other elements (like the `GridPane` in the first example of the tutorial).

Comment: From above the very example you posted: "The code in Example 4-4 is part of the `GridPane` layout and must be placed above the `</GridPane>` statement."

Answer (score 1):

your fxml file is missing a root element that will act as a container for the rest of the UI elements, according to what you posted your root element should be a grid pane

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

    <GridPane fx:controller="fxmlexample.FXMLExampleController" 
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
         <padding><Insets top="25" right="25" bottom="10" left="25"/></padding>
         <Text text="Welcome" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"
         GridPane.columnSpan="2"/>

         <Label text="User Name:"
         GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

        <Label text="Password:"
        GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>

        <PasswordField fx:id="passwordField" 
        GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
        <!-- rest of the elements ... -->

    </GridPane>
```